# How to filter particular string in column with Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, filtering, delete-row, data-cleaning

I have a data set with a column contains STATE/UT names and also "Total" with state names.

Now i want to filter data with text contains %Total% and delete those rows (below is the screen shot)
[image]

Can anyone suggest how to clean this?

Comment: How are you wanting to do this? Formula, VBA, Python? Can you provide an example of an attempt you've made?

Comment: @xTwisteDx with Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### for %TOTAL% use `find`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'STATE/UT': ['TOTAL(STATES)', 'TOTAL(UTs)', 'Normal'],
    'CRIME HEAD': ['RAPE', 'RAPE', 'RAPE']
})
df[df['STATE/UT'].str.find('TOTAL') == -1]
```

Comment: Thanks @Prince Francis i have used only deletion code and it work. Crime=Crime[Crime['STATE/UT'].str.find('TOTAL') == -1] and Crime=Crime[Crime['CRIME HEAD'].str.find('TOTAL') == -1]